# How to add missing value data in POWER BI / using SQL

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I have a table containing below data which might have missing information. But in that case , it should appear and shown as zero.I tried cross join but its performance is bad since it will create large number of records.

```
material location week value
123       p1      wk11  9
123       p1      wk13  13
456       p2      wk11  8
456       p2      wk12  7
```

desired o/p: (for material 123). in short, all possible combination of material and plant and week  will have value .

```
material location week value
123       p1      wk11  9
123       p1      wk12  0
123       p1      wk13  13
123       p2      wk11  0
123       p2      wk13  0
123       p2      wk12  0
```

Comment: *I tried cross join but its performance is bad since it will create large number of records.* CROSS JOIN is the only way to generate all possible combinations. Restrict generated rows with ones which contains the values which are needed in really, use according WHERE conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT  123 AS material,
        y.location,
        z.week,
        COALESCE(y.value, 0) AS value
    FROM table_with_list_of_all_wks AS z
    LEFT JOIN your_table AS y  ON y.week = z.week
    WHERE y.location = 'p1'
```

This requires pre-building a table with all possible "wk" values.

`y.value` will be `NULL` when a row (week) is missing; `COALESCE` turns that into `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rick. I cant do hard cording since i have millions of material and more than 10 locations and 20 plus weeks. I hope you get the complexity

Comment: @rameshreddy - Please provide another example.

Comment: it may be as below: (trying to make it bit simpler) . I want to fill in the missing sequence. if for a material , i have only p1 , p2 . But i also want to add p3 , hence it will shows the missing records as well

Comment: @rameshreddy - Perhaps:  Another `LEFT JOIN` from a list of all the locations.